# How to create update trigger for table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, triggers

I created PC Audit Application in C#. In SQL server management studio, I created database Audit. In Audit database, we have 4 tables name as computers,diskDrives, memory, software, users. I want to create update trigger for all 4 tables.

Comment: I edited my que. Plz change my que. status.

Answer (score 2):

Triggers cannot be delayed. They run synchronously since they have to abort the whole transaction if it fails.

You have to use [SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) for schedules SQL tasks.

Comment: But I want more explanation from your side. how to create update trigger for tables.

Comment: @knagis, I edited my que.. If you understand my que. plz reply.